# Does Max break the linearity between the dependent and independent variables needed for logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, nonlinear-regression

I want to use logistic regression to learn the coefficients of a function looks like that (a - the variables and w - the coefficients):

y = max(a1*w1 , a2*w2) + max(max(a3*w3 , a4*w4) , max(a5*b5 , a6*b6)) + max(a7*w7 , a8*w8) + …

however I’m not sure if the max function breaks the linearity between the dependent variable and the independent variables needed for logistic regression?

If so, what is the alternative to lean the coefficients if my labels (y) are binary or ordinal?

Comment: What do the symbols in your equation mean? When you say "max()", do you mean the largest value of a1w1 + a2w2 across all units in the data (which is a single value), or do you mean the largest of a1w1 and a2w2 for each unit (in which case, why did you include "+" between them?)?

Comment: This is not a linear model (a linear function of the coefficients)  , so you can't estimate it with logistic regression.

Comment: Hi Omri and welcome to the site! As pointed out in the comments above, your notation is not complete, since $\max(a,b)$ requires 2 values. Do you mean $\max$ between those values and $0$? Regardless, the $\max()$ operator is not linear, since it has a kink between the two values, i.e. a "hockey-stick" form for $\max(a,0)$ if $a$ is a linear function.

Comment: @Noah you are right, I fixed the equation. the max is the largest value between the a1w1, a2w2 and etc

Comment: @MichaelM that is what i thought, so there is an alternative to learn the coefficients if my labels (y) is binary or ordinal?

Comment: @PaulG thank you. I've fixed the equation. so if i can't use logistic regression, there is another alternative to learn the coefficients if my labels (y) is binary or ordinal?

Comment: You can use other non-linear methods that don't require the specification of a structure, for example KNN, trees and tree-based methods (such as bagging, boosting, random forests, xgboost) or neural networks. Right now I can't think of a standard method that allows you to keep the structure you imposed. Maybe it's possible do define a loss function (e.g. squared loss) and use gradient descent with your structure, but that would require first-order derivatives which is tricky due to the non-differentiability of max(). Maybe max() can be approximated with a differentiable function...?

Comment: Since the question in your title was answered, you could open another question around this topic, something like "What learning method can I use for a regression containing max()?". Maybe Non-linear Least Squares (NLS) or something can be applied. I'd also be interested if someone with more knowledge on this can answer.

Comment: @PaulG Thank you!